# Get and display data from server using ajax

Tags: ajax

I'm trying to learn ajax but I'm having a difficult time.

I have a java servlet that will give me data from a DB, and I'm trying to make a simple web page that continuously asks for an update every 5 seconds, and then displays it without having to reload the page. I also don't want to do this on a ready state change, but simply do it once every 5 seconds.

```
// xmlHttp = xmlHttpRequest object
function process() {
    try {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState==0) {
            xmlHttp.open("GET",'localhost:8080',true);
            //handleServerResponse();  // Get data from server. Not on ready state change, but always ?

            setInterval('process()', 5000);
        } else {
            setTimeout('process()', 5000);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        alert('main process did not work');
        alert(e.toString());
    }
}
```

I am unsure of how I could accomplish this. What's missing ?

Answer (score 1):

the following steps involved getting data from the server.

1. make a ajax request object and open the connection
2. and then send the request to the server
3. the server continuously sends response while processing the request. ex. 200 will the send when the request is successful and 404 when it cannot find the resource. ready state tells us how state of the request there are 5 states which informs us state of our request with the server . [LOOK HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)
4. only when readystate is 4 and status is 200. your request to the server is successful and you get a response in `request.responseHTML` or `request.responseXML`. which you use it for processing.

   ```
   windown.onload = initialize;
   function initialize()
   {
       setInterval(process, 5000);
   }

   var request ;
   function process()
   {
      request = getAJAXREQUETOBJECT;
      request.open("get","URL",true);
      request.onreadystatechange = requestresponse;
      request.send(true);
   }

   function requestresponse()
   {
      if(request.readystate == 4 && request.status == 200)
      {
        // do manipulation with request.responseHTML or request.responseXML
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways it could be done. See below. I provided some simplification to put emphasis on the solution.

First approach. Use `setInterval()` outside `process()`

```
function process() {
    url = "http://localhost:9090";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET",url,true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
             // handle response (xhr.responseText)  
        }
    }

    xhr.send();
}

//and then
setInterval(process, 5000);
```

Another. Use `setTimeout()` inside `process()`

```
function process() {
    url = "http://localhost:9090";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET",url,true);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
             // handle response (xhr.responseText)

             setTimeout(process, 5000); 
        }
    }

    xhr.send();
}

//and then
process();
```

The difference between `setTimeout()` and `setInterval` is that the first one will run `process()` once while the latter one is a loop. So if you used `interval()` inside `process()` the number of requests would grow exponentially.